# What response should If-Modified-Since HTTP Header return if request is HEAD?

Tags: http, header, if-modified-since

If you send a GET request with an If-Modified-Since header, the server suports it and the file hasn't changed, the server will return a 304 response.

If you sent a HEAD request in the same circumstances, should the server send a 304 response or send back the full headers you would have sent had the file changed?

In short: is GET / HEAD equivalent when requesting a file that has not changed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per [RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)

> The HEAD method is identical to GET
>   except that the server MUST NOT return
>   a message-body in the response. The
>   metainformation contained in the HTTP
>   headers in response to a HEAD request
>   SHOULD be identical to the information
>   sent in response to a GET request.

Based on the above,  the HEAD request in the same circumstances should return 304.

> In short: is GET / HEAD equivalent
>   when requesting a file that has not
>   changed?

Again, based on what the RFC has to say, both GET and HEAD should be equivalent.

Comment: @suresh-kumar That's what I thought, glad to get confirmation. Thanks!